# phpMyAdmin has two database tables under one heading

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin

I am in the process of moving my local website onto a live webhost and am having some confusion while exporting my database tables from phpMyAdmin.

I attached a screenshot for reference.

It seems as if there are two database tables that are being used for my website, I'm not sure how this happened though. **What I am trying to figure out is which database table is the one that I need to export along with all my Joomla files?**

I went into my htdocs to check the configuration.php file and it says that the database prefix is xxx (i made this up) BUT when I go look into that database table (on phpMyAdmin) the dates of creation don't match up but are current in the "other database table."

Thank you for your help.

[Screenshot for reference](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/ohu.png/)

Comment: You do have two databases, campuscoop and campuscoop_June10 which might be a leftover from an old backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ascertain which is the correct database, create a new user via the Joomla interface, then have a look at the users Joomla table via phpMyAdmin, in both databases, to see in which database the user got created.

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found in your site's admin at Site => Global Configuration => Server